# magento 2 : Data tool migration transform date/time

Tags: magento2, migration, date

I have a problem with the tool for the migration of data.
My old magento use 1.7.0.2 end my new magento use 2.1.

Actually, my column purchase date are transformed with strange differences.

I verified the configuration in my php.ini!All is well. I don't know what i can do to solve the problem.

in documentation, it is said

> The Data Migration Tool has special handler \Migration\Handler\Timezone for transforming time to a different time zone. Using it you can change time for some fields of database. These fields can be specified in your map.xml file with offset parameter.

Then I looked in the file map.xml.
i think it need to copy this code :

`<transform> 
  <field>cms_page.root_template</field> <handler class="\Migration\Handler\Convert"> <param name="map" value="[one_column:1column;two_columns_left:2columns-left;two_columns_right:2columns-right;three_columns:3columns]" /> </handler> 
</transform>`

but i don't know what are fields i must change, and what do I have to change in section param?

i thank you for your help.

Comment: can u please help on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291709/magento-2-data-migration-time-difference